# Tool for linking/managing multiple parallel code bases?

Tags: cross-platform

I'm trying to find a tool to assist in native development for multiple platforms in parallel. Let's get it out of the way: I'm not looking for write-once-run-on-multiple-platforms toolkits. I'm envisioning more of a "code management" tool...

I'm imagining a tool that captures and leverages metadata about parallel code-bases. For instance, I would like to be able to say "file X and file Y are linked, but file X is for platform A, and file Y is for platform B". Then later, if I make a change to file X, ideally such a tool would alert me, like: "Hey! You changed file X, but not Y." or "You changed file Y but not X." Ideally, such a tool would be able to manage these relationships at a finer granularity than just files (like, perhaps lines within files), and would also have good integration with mainstream source control packages (Git, SVN).

So, does such a thing exist? It has proven challenging to google for this, because relevant terms like "multi-platform" and "parallel" are so overloaded -- I found myself awash in write-once toolkits and parallel processing frameworks, so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: A version control tool can probably do this for you, if you are using GIT or subversion could you not simply branch the file sets off to keep them organized?  If you have things branched by platform you can simply diff...What kind of code are you talking about managing.  How many users, etc.